# Deep copy of abstract object

Tags: java, copy

Java here. I've got the following situation:

```
abstract class A { /*...*/ };
class Derived1 extends A { /*...*/ };
class Derived2 extends A { /*...*/ };
class Derived3 extends A { /*...*/ };
```

and elsewhere in the code someone sends me objects of type 'A':

```
A obj1 = getObject();
```

now I'd like to do a deep copy of object 'obj1', something like

```
A obj2 = obj1.deepCopy();
```

but I don't know how to implement this. I don't know the type of obj1 (well, it is either Derived1, Derived2 or Derived3). 
Is it possible to write a deep copy function once and avoid doing things like

```
if( obj1 instancef Derived1 ) 
  {
  A obj2 = new Derived1((Derived1)obj1);
  }
```

and having to implement three copy constructors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes by using a polymorphic `deepCopy` method.

```java
abstract class A {
    A(A t) {
    }

    A() {}

    public abstract A deepCopy();
}
```

```java
class D1 extends A {

    D1(D1 t) {
        //copy constructor
    }

    D1() {
        //no-arg constructor
    }

    @Override
    public D1 deepCopy() {                        
        return new D1(this);
    }
}
```

```java
A a = new D1();
A copy = a.deepCopy(); //the deepCopy is called D1 class
```